# trigger mysql on insert, insert pk in other table

Tags: mysql, triggers, insert

actually i have a table products and a table price_history, in the table price history i have a fk_id_prod and the price

my trigger looks like this:

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS price_insert $$
CREATE TRIGGER price_insert BEFORE INSERT
ON products
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

INSERT INTO prices_history(id_prod, price) VALUES (NEW.id_prod, NEW.price);

END;
$$
```

I just learned how to create triggers so there may be some mistakes,.

My problem:

i cannot insert any data in my table products due to the fk constraint.

How do i deal with it?

Thanks for your help

Comment: sorry my stupid mistake.

i triggered before instead of after insert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `table prices_history` has foreign key on `product`, the record on `product` must exists *before* storing the corresponding `prices_history`

Maybe your trigger should be fired `AFTER INSERT`, not `BEFORE INSERT` ?